Need help with tikzpicture: how to generate a drawing form a list of characters?
I have this code that creates a tikzpicture with an example schedule as a gantchart for 3 workers. But I want to be able to set the sequence of f,s,n shifts individually, so that e.g. worker 1 [f,f,f,s,n,n,n] works and then only these seven squares are displayed, the rest is white. And how do I align the days of the week above with the boxes of the shifts.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\def\fieldOne{{\tiny Mon}}
\def\fieldTwo{{\tiny Tue}}
\def\fieldThree{{\tiny Wed}}
\def\fieldFour{{\tiny Thu}}
\def\fieldFive{{\tiny Fro}}
\def\fieldSix{{\tiny Sat}}
\def\fieldSeven{{\tiny Sun}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, outer sep=0pt},
    f/.style={box, fill=cyan!30},
    s/.style={box, fill=magenta!50},
    n/.style={box, fill=green!50},
    text_field/.style={box, fill=yellow!20, minimum height=0.5cm, text width=1cm, align=center},
]

\node[text_field] at (0, 3) {\fieldOne};
\node[text_field] at (1, 3) {\fieldTwo};
\node[text_field] at (2, 3) {\fieldThree};
\node[text_field] at (3, 3) {\fieldFour};
\node[text_field] at (4, 3) {\fieldFive};
\node[text_field] at (5, 3) {\fieldSix};
\node[text_field] at (6, 3) {\fieldSeven};

% Define shifts
\foreach \worker [count=\i from 0] in {1, 2, 3} {
    % Early shift (f)
    \foreach \x in {0,1,6} {
        \node[f] at (\x, 2.5-\i*1.5) {f};
    }
    % Late shift (s)
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
        \node[s] at (\x, 2-\i*1.5) {s};
    }
    % Night shift (n)
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
        \node[n] at (\x, 1.5-\i*1.5) {n};
    }
    % Worker labels
    \node[anchor=east] at (-0.52, 2.5-\i*1.5) {Worker \worker};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Maybe have a look if pgfgantt might be useful?

Kindly see my change of your title as a suggestion. Feel free to adapt it differently.

Here is a way to do it. I'll show the result and code first and explain some details after that.

\documentclass[border=3mm,]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

% ~~~ some constants ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\def\fOne{{\tiny Mon}}
\def\fTwo{{\tiny Tue}}
\def\fThree{{\tiny Wed}}
\def\fFour{{\tiny Thu}}
\def\fFive{{\tiny Fri}}
\def\fSix{{\tiny Sat}}
\def\fSeven{{\tiny Sun}}

% ~~~ some commands ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% ~~~ set offset "array" ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\soffs[2]{\expandafter\def\csname offs#1\endcsname{#2}}
% creates \def\offsf, \def\offss and \def\offsn, with values passed by #2

% ~~~ get its value ~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\goffs[1]{\csname offs#1\endcsname}

% ~~~ 1 line of a worker ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\wrk[3]{% 1: workName, 2: y-offset, 3: shift list
    \node[anchor=south east] at (-1,#2) {#1:};%
    \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {#3}%
        \node[\a] at (\i,#2 + \goffs{\a}) {\a};
    % ~~~ a line for better visability ~~~~~~~
    \draw[dotted] (0, #2-1) -- +(7,0);}
    
        
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

 % ~~~ setting node offsets for the shifts ~~~~~~~
 \soffs{f}{0}
 \soffs{s}{-.5}
 \soffs{n}{-1}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw,anchor=south west,
                minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, outer sep=0pt},
    f/.style={box, fill=cyan!30},
    s/.style={box, fill=magenta!50},
    n/.style={box, fill=green!50},
    text_field/.style={box, fill=yellow!20,align=center},
]

    % ~~~ Weekdays ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \w [count=\i from 0] in {\fOne,\fTwo,\fThree,\fFour,
                                      \fFive,\fSix,\fSeven}
        \node[text_field] at (\i,.5) {\w};

    % ~~~ SCHEDULES ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %   % ~~~ for development => refactored into \wrk ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %   \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {f,f,f,s,n,n,n}
    %       \node[\a] at (\i,\goffs{\a}) {\a};

    \wrk{Harry}     { 0  }{f,s,s,n,n,f}
    \wrk{Gerd}      {-1.5}{s,s,s,f,f,n,n}
    \wrk{Worker 3}  {-3  }{f,f,f,s,n,n,n}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Intended functionality
I assume, in the end you want to do sth. like

pass workers name
indicate vertical position
pass a list with the individual schedules

    \wrk{Worker 3}  {-3  }{f,f,f,s,n,n,n}

Developing this
Commented out you see an intermediate step I used to display just one worker, where the second line is key:

\a will be f, s or n
because you named the nodes-styles also f, s and n, \node[\a] selects the right style
\goffs{\a} retrieves a vertical offset to shift the boxes down, as needed (lookup)
i.e. the lists sequence determines the visual outcome now

    % ~~~ SCHEDULES ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        % ~~~ for development => refactored into \wrk ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {f,f,f,s,n,n,n}
            \node[\a] at (\i,\goffs{\a}) {\a};

Vertical offsets
The idea is to use a kind of TeX array, which holds offsets offs, can be set via \soffs{}{}, and values can be got (retrieved) via \goffs{}. Here's the TeX trick:
% ~~~ set offset "array" ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\soffs[2]{\expandafter\def\csname offs#1\endcsname{#2}}
% creates \def\offsf, \def\offss and \def\offsn, with values passed by #2
% WHEN you use the initialization mentioned below

% ~~~ get its value ~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\goffs[1]{\csname offs#1\endcsname}

There are many more alternatives to create this kind of data or lookup functionality.
Later you initiate them:
 % ~~~ setting node offsets for the shifts ~~~~~~~
 \soffs{f}{0}
 \soffs{s}{-.5}
 \soffs{n}{-1}

The \wrk macro
It contains basically the code from aboves development, with some extensions.
% ~~~ 1 line of a worker ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\wrk[3]{% 1: workName, 2: y-offset, 3: shift list
    \node[anchor=south east] at (-1,#2) {#1:};%
    \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {#3}%
        \node[\a] at (\i,#2 + \goffs{\a}) {\a};
    % ~~~ a line for better visability ~~~~~~~
    \draw[dotted] (0, #2-1) -- +(7,0);}

Other changes made to your code
I simplified your styles, i.e. removed some of the redundancies, and used dedicated anchor points.
The topline with the weekdays now is also just a loop, with calls to your simplified field-names in the list.
There is no error checking, i.e. other characters for the shifts won't work or are silently ignored etc.
P.S.
As you can see, I forgot one shift with Harry. That's no problem, the list is just shorter.
However, putting an empty entry fails to compile, like {f,s,s,n,,n,f} , as there is no style which starts with nothing. (If there would be, it would err a few characters later for other reasons.) // You can easily accoount for this by introducing a new letter, and adjusting color and offset.
